# How to get all participants from Event

Tags: soql, relationships

How get all participant from each Event and check if they are leads or not? Is it possible with one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it with single query:

```
Set<Id> leadIds = new Set<Id>();

for(EventRelation e : [SELECT RelationId FROM 
    EventRelation WHERE EventId = 'SOME_EVENT_ID' AND Status = 'Accepted' AND RelationId in (Select Id From Lead)])
{
    leadIds.add(e.RelationId);
}
```

Also, just in case if you have a list of Event Ids in a variable called `eventIds`, you can rewrite the query to be like this:

```
[SELECT RelationId FROM 
    EventRelation WHERE EventId in :eventIds AND Status = 'Accepted' AND RelationId in (Select Id From Lead)]
```

For more info on `EventRelation` object check this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventattendee.htm?search_text=EventRelation)

**EDIT**

I'm adding here the 2nd approach that I would actually prefer, even though it's not a single query as OP requested:

```
Set<Id> participantIds = new Set<Id>();

for(EventRelation e : [SELECT RelationId FROM 
    EventRelation WHERE EventId = 'SOME_EVENT_ID' AND Status = 'Accepted'])
{
    participantIds.add(e.RelationId);
}

List<Lead> leads = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Lead WHERE Id in :participantIds];
```

I prefer this second approach simply because I'm not sure how taxing it is to call the following part of the query in the first approach - `RelationId in (Select Id From Lead)`.